# Similarity A,B, and two other invertible matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

Well, if I have A similar to B. Is it necessary true for every two invertible matrices P,Q (dimension n) that $P^{-1}AP$ and $Q^{-1}BQ$ are similar? I guess it is. But I'm not sure. maybe a hint?

Comment: Yes, is it true. You have to smuggle in something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $A$ and $B$ are similar then there's $T$ an invertible matrix such that
$$A=T^{-1}BT$$
so we have
$$P^{-1}AP=P^{-1}T^{-1}BTP==P^{-1}T^{-1}Q\left(Q^{-1}BQ\right)Q^{-1}TP=S^{-1}\left(Q^{-1}BQ\right)S$$
where $S=Q^{-1}TP$ hence $P^{-1}AP$ and $Q^{-1}BQ$ are similar.

Comment: Thank you veru much @user63181

Comment: You're welcome.